# Multiplying a matrix and a vector in C

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, malloc

I want to multiply a matrix and a vector, I already wrote the functions to store the matrix and vector in malloc arrays. For this function, I need to create another array using malloc to store my answer first. then do the calculations (http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/mastascu/elessonsHTML/Circuit/MatVecMultiply.htm)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* Multiply a matrix by a vector. */
double *matrix_vector_multiply(int rows, int cols,
               double **mat, double *vec){

 // creating an vecotr to hold the answer first

 double *ans= malloc(rows* sizeof(double));

 // do the multiplication:
 mulitply **mat and *vec (mat = the matrix and vec is the vector)

 for (rows=0; rows< ; rows++)
    for (cols=0; cols< ; cols++)
        ans[rows] = ans[rows] + vec[rows][cols] * mat[rows];    

 //not sure if it is right

 // then store the answer back to the ans array            


}
```

the main function:

```
double *matrix_vector_multiply(int rows, int cols,
               double **mat, double *vec);

int main(){
  double *answer = matrix_vector_multiply(rows, cols, matrix, vector);

  printf("Answer vector: \n");
  print_vector(rows, answer);
  return 0;
 }
```

not sure how to do this multiplication with pointers and then storing it back.. 
any help would be appreciated! thanks!

edit: the multiply function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* Multiply a matrix by a vector. */
double *matrix_vector_multiply(int rows, int cols,
               double **mat, double *vec){

double *ans = malloc(rows * sizeof (double));   
int i;  
for (i=0; i<rows; rows++)
    for (i=0; i<cols; cols++)
        ans[rows] = ans[rows] + vec[rows][cols] * mat[rows];    

return ans;
```

}

but i am getting a error at line 12, subscripted value is either array nor pointer

Comment: If you can't do pointers, do array operations which should be more obvious. If you have `double* vec`, then you can access `vec[0]`, `vec[1]` etc.

Comment: Multiplying a matrix by a vector produces a vector, not a matrix, so you should just have a single `double *ans = malloc(rows * sizeof (double));` to hold the answer.  You can then access each element of the input matrix using `mat[i][j]` and each element of the input vector using `vec[i]`, so just apply the usual maths to calculate each element of the answer, and store it in `ans[i]`.

Comment: j_random_hacker is right. Actually, the function `matrix_vector_multiply` is defined to return an array of doubles, so the result you are attempting to produce is incompatible with the function return value (`ans` is of type double**, not double*). Is it homework?

Comment: you are right, the ans should be a vector. I just made some edits. I will put the math part in and you can see if it is correct

Comment: should i add return ans; at the end?

Comment: don't use an emulation of a 2D array. C has 2D arrays builtin to the language, use them.

Answer (score 2):

There are several mistakes in your functions:

1. the variables for iterating through the matrix in the for loops shouldn't be the arguments you passed to your function. Try with something like this: 
   `for(y=0;y<rows;y++)`
2. you have to swap `vec` and `mat` in the for loops
3. you will have to initialize your answer vector to `0` (another for loop)
4. you have to return the answer (`return ans;`) at the end of your multiplication

Hope that helps,
Jan

Comment: Hey sl, this is my edited function, the math is not right i dont think:

#include <stdlib.h>

/* Multiply a matrix by a vector. */

double *matrix_vector_multiply(int rows, int cols,
                               double **mat, double *vec)
{

        double *ans = malloc(rows * sizeof (double));
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<rows; rows++)
        ans[i]=0;

        for (i=0; i<rows; rows++)
            for (i=0; i<cols; cols++)
                ans[rows] = ans[rows] + mat[rows][cols] * vec[rows];

        return ans;
}

Comment: you have to increment the `i` not `rows` in the for-loop and you'll need two variables in the for-loops for the multiplication: one that goes from `0` to `rows-1` and another one that goes from `0` to `cols-1`